# vba, How can I delete filtered data from a worksheet in a listbox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have created a userform which when opened displays the data from a workbook (cells A to H) in a listbox named `lstNewDisplay`
I have a piece of code (below) which filters the data based on a value entered within a text box `txtNewSearch`
I want to create a button which can delete a row selected from the list box `lstNewDisplay` and remove that row from the row on the worksheet.
The button would need to be able to delete the row of filtered and unfiltered data.
I have tried a few different pieces of code to get this working, however when the data is filtered it deletes the wrong row. However I have had some success deleting the unfiltered row. If there is no way to have the code delete both filtered and unfiltered data, I would rather it deleted the filtered data row from the listbox and workbook.

Sorry if I am not explaining this well, I am very new to via and learning as I go along.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
lstNewDisplay.RowSource = ""
lstNewDisplay.Value = ""
Dim i As Long
On Error Resume Next
Me.lstNewDisplay.Clear
For i = 2 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet2.Range("A:A"))
For x = 1 To 8
a = Len(Me.txtNewSearch.Text)
If Left(Sheet2.Cells(i, x).Value, a) = Me.txtNewSearch.Text And Me.txtNewSearch.Text <> "" Then
Me.lstNewDisplay.AddItem Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Value
For c = 1 To 8
Me.lstNewDisplay.List(lstNewDisplay.ListCount - 1, c) = Sheet2.Cells(i, c + 1).Value
Next c
End If
Next x
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So, this is what I came up with... give it a try and see it works for you. I had to modify most of your code.

To accomplish your goal, the first thing I had to do was to change the `Private Sub UserForm_Activate()` event since you probably are using `lstNewDisplay.RowSource =` to assign the range for the listbox, the thing is that we need to know from what worksheet row came each row that is on the list, that way we can later tell excel which worksheet row to delete.

So my event looks like this...

**Note:** That I'm using a collection global variable to keep the worksheet row for later use.

```
Option Explicit
Private coll As Collection
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

 Dim LastRow As Long
 Dim a As Long
 Dim b As Long
 Dim i As Long

 LastRow = Sheets("Filter").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 Set coll = New Collection

 a = 0
 b = 1

 For i = 2 To LastRow

 coll.Add i
 With Me.lstNewDisplay

 .AddItem
 .List(a, 0) = Sheets("Filter").Cells(i, 1)
 .List(a, 1) = Sheets("Filter").Cells(i, 2)
 .List(a, 2) = Sheets("Filter").Cells(i, 3)
 .List(a, 3) = Sheets("Filter").Cells(i, 4)
 .List(a, 4) = Sheets("Filter").Cells(i, 5)
 .List(a, 5) = Sheets("Filter").Cells(i, 6)
 .List(a, 6) = Sheets("Filter").Cells(i, 7)
 .List(a, 7) = Sheets("Filter").Cells(i, 8)

 End With

 b = b + 1
 a = a + 1

 Next

End Sub
```

And this is how I code the filter button...

```
Private Sub btnFiltered_Click()

  Dim LastRow As Long
  Dim LastColumn As Long
  Dim c As Range
  Dim a As Long
  Dim b As Long
  Dim firstaddress As String

  If Me.txtNewSearch.Text <> "" Then

  Set coll = New Collection
  Me.lstNewDisplay.RowSource = ""
  Me.lstNewDisplay.Clear

  LastRow = Sheets("Filter").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  LastColumn = Sheets("Filter").Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

  a = 0
  b = 0

  With Sheets("Filter").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
  Set c = .Find(Me.txtNewSearch.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

  If Not c Is Nothing Then
  firstaddress = c.Address

   Do

   With Me.lstNewDisplay
  .AddItem

  .List(a, 0) = Sheets("Filter").Cells(c.Row, 1)
  .List(a, 1) = Sheets("Filter").Cells(c.Row, 2)
  .List(a, 2) = Sheets("Filter").Cells(c.Row, 3)
  .List(a, 3) = Sheets("Filter").Cells(c.Row, 4)
  .List(a, 4) = Sheets("Filter").Cells(c.Row, 5)
  .List(a, 5) = Sheets("Filter").Cells(c.Row, 6)
  .List(a, 6) = Sheets("Filter").Cells(c.Row, 7)
  .List(a, 7) = Sheets("Filter").Cells(c.Row, 8)

  a = a + 1

  End With

  coll.Add c.Row

  Set c = .FindNext(c)

  If c Is Nothing Then
  GoTo DoneFinding
  End If

  Loop While c.Address <> firstaddress
  End If

DoneFinding:
  End With

  End If


End Sub
```

And finally here it is the delete button...

```
Private Sub btndelete_Click()

Dim i As Long
Dim a As Long
Dim item As Variant

For i = 0 To Me.lstNewDisplay.ListCount - 1

If Me.lstNewDisplay.Selected(i) Then

For a = 1 To coll.Count

If Sheets("Filter").Cells(coll.item(a), 1).Text = Me.lstNewDisplay.List(i, 0) And Sheets("Filter").Cells(coll.item(a), 8).Text = Me.lstNewDisplay.List(i, 7) Then

Me.lstNewDisplay.RemoveItem (i)
Sheets("Filter").Rows(coll.item(a)).EntireRow.Delete
coll.Remove (a)
Exit For

End If

Next

End If

Next

End Sub
```